# Metal Compute function causes GPU timeout error

Tags: gpgpu, metal

I am trying to compute the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) for a range of numbers to see how much I can benefit from using the GPU. For some reason, the function seems to fail for integers above one hundred million. I use 64-bit unsigned long for the calculations, so it can't be integer overflow; the largest number reached in the calculations for any integer is well below the maximum representable value for this datatype.

The application is basically Apple's [Performing Calculations on a GPU](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/basic_tasks_and_concepts/performing_calculations_on_a_gpu?preferredLanguage=occ), where the array buffers and fragment function are the only things changed. The basic idea for the function is to pass an array of integers (say from 1 to 1000), where each integer serves as a starting point for a while-loop performing the Collatz calculations for every number until the thread reaches a top set limit, for example, a billion.

```
kernel void compute_collatz(device const unsigned int *array [[buffer(0)]],
                       device unsigned int *result [[buffer(1)]],
                       uint index [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    const unsigned long arrayLength = (unsigned long)1000;
    unsigned long arrayNumber = (unsigned long)array[index];
    unsigned long maxNumber = (unsigned long)1000000000 - arrayLength;

    while (arrayNumber <= maxNumber) {

        unsigned long curentStep = arrayNumber;
        while (curentStep != 1) {
            
            if (curentStep % 2 == 0) {curentStep = curentStep / 2;}
            else {curentStep = (curentStep * 3) + 1;}
        }

        arrayNumber += arrayLength;
    }
    result[index] = (int)arrayNumber;
}
```

When the function reaches the maximum limit, it stores that value in a different array. This works well when the maximum value is sett to one hundred million or less, but only about one third of the array is changed when I try higher values. The program fails with the following error: `Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Timeout Error (IOAF code 2)`. I had a similar problem when I tried multithreading on the CPU for the first time, but then the problem was related to pointers. Can't see that this is a problem here.

I am using Xcode 12.5.1 on macOS 11.5.2 on a MacBook Pro 16 (2016). Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `GPU Timeout Error` means the kernel ran for a longer time than the operating system imposed limit, typically around 2 seconds. This limit is designed to prevent the GUI from freezing due to computer kernels with excessive run time. Possible solutions: (1) Use a faster GPU (2) Increase the time-out limit; how to do this is OS-dependent and off-topic here (3) split the work across multiple kernel invocations, so each invocation can execute in less time than the limit. (4) check whether you can configure the GPU as a non-GUI-serving device that is not subject to the operating system time limit.

Comment: I am pretty sure there's no robust way for an application on Apple devices to change the GPU timeout, except for private APIs that are private for a reason. Using faster GPU still means that there is a slower GPU which isn't going to support whatever you are writing. And I don't know a way to configure a GPU for long-running tasks on either macOS or iOS. So the only real way to work around this is scheduling the work in smaller increments. Basically, splitting up the work into multiple command buffers.